# Draw table as grob in R

Tags: r, gridextra, grob

I am trying to implement functionality of `gridExtra` package in `R` to display tables as graphics objects. The examples from tutorial [Displaying tables as grid graphics/Aesthetic formatting](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html#aesthetic-formatting) work fine, but when I do my own graphics like below it gives me `Error in cbind_2(gr, g, "max") : nrow(x) == nrow(y) is not TRUE`.

What is wrong and how to resolve the issue? Expected behavior is `grob` object which can be shown on screen by `grid.arrange` function.

```
    df<-tibble(A=c("A", "B"), B=1:2)
    tt<-ttheme_minimal(core=list(bg_params = list(fill = blues9[1:2])))
    grid.newpage()
    g<-tableGrob(df, tt)
    grid.arrange(g)
```

Comment: Second parameter of the `tableGrob` function is `rows`. So you need to specific the the name of the parameter in your call like this: `g<-tableGrob(df, theme = tt)`.